# How to do alternative install of Homebrew

Tags: macos, maven, terminal, homebrew

Ok, well it's just been one of those nights where you spend hours and hours trying to get something to work, and you just keep getting weird errors, so if someone could help me I would greatly appreciate. After hours of trying to update Maven from 3.0.4 to 3.1.1 or 3.2.2 I've decided it's just not going to happen (I've tried almost everything I can find online, but I'm afraid to try to do to much in terminal) and I'm trying to install homebrew to make it easier. When I try to do the normal homebrew install I get an error that says:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Failed during: git init -q

So then, I tried to do the alternative install method, but at this point I'm just so annoyed, and I don't get what it wants me to do. If anyone could give me some at least kind of detailed explanation for what to do I would be extremely grateful.

Here's where I'm looking at alternative installs: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation

The problem is I don't even really know what they mean by "untar" and "extract."

Thanks so much to anyone who can help

When I enter

```
ls -l /usr/local | pbcopy
```

I get:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Aug 11 03:34 apache-maven
drwxrwxr-x  81 root  admin  2754 Jan 17  2014 bin
drwxrwxr-x   3 root  admin   102 Feb 21  2013 etc
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  wheel   306 Jul 25 14:54 git
drwxrwxr-x   3 root  admin   102 Feb 21  2013 lib
drwxrwxr-x   4 root  admin   136 Feb 20  2013 share
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136 Dec 14  2013 texlive
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Ok, so let's do an alternative install of `homebrew`:

```
cd /usr/local
mkdir homebrew
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

If that works, you just need to find the directory where the file `brew` is located and then add that to your PATH

So

```
find /usr/local -name brew
```

Let's suppose the previous command results in

```
/usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew
```

we take `brew` off the end (because we want to know its directory only) and we add that to the start of our PATH

```
export PATH=/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Now we should be able to run

```
brew doctor
```

Also, we need to add that `export PATH=....` command to our login sequence so our shell knows how to find `brew` every time we login. So add that line to the end of your `~/.profile`

**Original Answer**

Ok, take a deep breath, and relax :-)

`homebrew` is a great choice on the Mac, so the pain should be worth it. I suspect you have a customised `PATH` and customised environment variables which are stopping the `homebrew` installation. You can either set your `PATH` and environment variables back to their default settings, or, if that is simpler, just add a new user to your Mac and log in as the new user with a standard environment and then install `homebrew` using the standard method.

To look at your `PATH` and environment variables, use these commands:

```
echo $PATH

set
```

or

```
set | grep -i LIB
```

to look for any customised DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Once you have it installed, try running

```
brew doctor
```

to check your setup before adding maven and other packages.

Comment: Ok, well, I tried checking my path, and this is what I got:

PATH=/Users/**********/rs/*********/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin

I'm guessing it shouldn't be this long... Also, I tried going to another user, and got the same error message. Not sure how anything got this messed up *sigh*.

Comment: Are your backups up-to-date? Can you run `ls -l /usr/local | pbcopy` and then click `edit` under your answer and paste into your answer (the command copies its output to the clipboard so you won't see anything till you paste).

Comment: @user3928789 I presume you are using `bash`? You can test with `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Yea, I'm using bash. And when I enterls -l /usr/local | pbcopy I get:         
      
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Aug 11 03:34 apache-maven
drwxrwxr-x  81 root  admin  2754 Jan 17  2014 bin
drwxrwxr-x   3 root  admin   102 Feb 21  2013 etc
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  wheel   306 Jul 25 14:54 git
drwxrwxr-x   3 root  admin   102 Feb 21  2013 lib
drwxrwxr-x   4 root  admin   136 Feb 20  2013 share
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136 Dec 14  2013 texlive

Comment: Do you want to try an alternative installation of homebrew? I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried that and didn't get any error messages. Now there's the homebrew folder inside of local with everything in it, but still when I try to do commands like brew doctor, it says "-bash: brew: command not found
" Do I need to do something special to use homebrew since I installed it this way?

Comment: You just need to find the directory where the file `brew` is located and then add that to your PATH. I'll update my answer.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!I really didn't think that I was ever going to get it to work.